# XSLT determine if a parameter value contains value based on xslt input loop

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, composite

I'm trying to loop across XML data to determine if a substring of the XML input is contained in the parameter TagIDs. Here is an example of the input:

```
 <in:inputs xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0">
<!-- Input Parameter, XPath /in:inputs/in:param[@name='TagTypeCode'] -->
<in:param name="TagTypeCode">USC_CATEGORY_tags</in:param>
<!-- Input Parameter, XPath /in:inputs/in:param[@name='keyword'] -->
<in:param name="keyword"/>
<!-- Input Parameter, XPath /in:inputs/in:param[@name='TagIDs'] -->
<in:param name="TagIDs">,2704,2764,</in:param>
<!-- Function Call Result (2 ms), XPath /in:inputs/in:result[@name='SolrSearchResults']/response -->
 <in:result name="SolrSearchResults">
     <response xmlns="">
         <lst name="responseHeader">
            <int name="status">0</int>
            <int name="QTime">1</int>
             <lst name="params">
                <str name="facet">true</str>
                <str name="start">0</str>
                <str name="q">*:* AND tagids:2704 AND tagids:2764</str>
                <str name="facet.field">USC_CATEGORY_tags</str>
                <str name="rows">0</str>
            </lst>
        </lst>
        <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
         <lst name="facet_counts">
            <lst name="facet_queries"/>
             <lst name="facet_fields">
                 <lst name="USC_CATEGORY_tags">
                    <int name="2703.Best Sellers">0</int>
                    <int name="2704.New Release">0</int>
                    <int name="2705.Training Products">0</int>
                    <int name="2706.AICP Exam Prep">0</int>
                    <int name="2707.PAS Reports">0</int>
                    <int name="2709.PAS Super Sale">0</int>
                    <int name="2722.Books Big Sale 2013">0</int>
                    <int name="2723.Books Big Sale 2013 - 20% Off">0</int>
                    <int name="2724.Books Big Sale 2013 - 50% Off">0</int>
                    <int name="2725.Books Big Sale 2013 - 80% Off">0</int>
                    <int name="2734.eBook Landing Page">0</int>
                    <int name="2736.eBook Landing Page">0</int>
                </lst>
            </lst>
            <lst name="facet_dates"/>
            <lst name="facet_ranges"/>
        </lst>
    </response>
</in:result>
```

Is it possible to loop across /in:inputs/in:result[@name='SolrSearchResults']/response/lst[@name='facet_counts']/lst[@name='facet_fields']/lst/int
to determine if **any** @name attribute (substring-before the '.') is contained in the TagIDs param, and if so, set a variable to some value? What would be the most efficient way?

Here's what I've tried

```
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/in:inputs/in:result[@name='SolrSearchResults']/response" />
    <xsl:variable name="TagIDs" select="/in:inputs/in:param[@name='TagIDs']" />
    <xsl:variable name="facet_selected" select="0"/>

<xsl:for-each select="$root/lst[@name='facet_counts']/lst[@name='facet_fields']/lst/int">
            <xsl:if test="contains($TagIDs,concat(',',substring-before(@name,'.'),','))" >
                <xsl:variable name="facet_selected" select="1" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

If you could point me in the right direction I'd much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do so like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:in="http://www.composite.net/ns/transformation/input/1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="root"
                  select="/in:inputs/in:result[@name='SolrSearchResults']
                                    /response" />
    <xsl:variable name="TagIDs"
                  select="/in:inputs/in:param[@name='TagIDs']" />
    <xsl:variable name="ints"
                  select="$root/lst[@name='facet_counts']
                               /lst[@name='facet_fields']/lst/int" />

    <xsl:variable name="matchingInts"
                  select="$ints[contains($TagIDs, 
                                         concat(',', 
                                                substring-before(@name, '.'), 
                                                ',')
                                        )]" />
    <!-- facet_selected will have the value 1 if matches were found, 0 if not -->
    <xsl:variable name="facet_selected" select="number(boolean($matchingInts))"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, `matchingInts` contains the `int` with name `2704.New Release` and `facet_selected` has the value 1.